# .Net Core 3.1 gRPC client with unencrypted HTTP2 connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc

I am trying to query some local gRPC services running on HTTP. This is my net core 3.1 console app:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:16050");
    var client = new EventService.EventServiceClient(channel);
    var reply1 = await client.GetTrackEventAsync(new GetTrackEventRequest { Name = "01Austra14" });
}
```

But it is throwing this error:

> An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred in
> System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code:
> 'Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call.
> HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the
> connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).",
> DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error
> occurred while sending the request.  --->
> System.Net.Http.Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent
> invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR'
> (0x1).

Unfortunately at the moment we can't add an SSL certificate and we need to use plain HTTP for a while (the service app is not in production yet). Does anyone have an idea on what is happening here?

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client) the `AppContext.SetSwitch` call should be enough.

The server is an Asp Net Core 3.1 app. It is running on:

- port http://*:16050
- port https://*:16150. **This replies correctly to the client** but as explained above, can be used only locally at the moment

The server provides

- Http1 and Http2
- **REST APIs and gRPC APIs on the same port**

Client is using the following packages

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.37.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.37.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It you can workaround it. Please read the link I provided. I already did it in the past

Comment: @phuzi that's not correct; gRPC and HTTP/2 works fine without TLS - it just isn't recommended, and needs an opt-in switch

Comment: The link doesn't work

Comment: Link fixed, points to ms doc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure this applies in your scenario (although the "Http1 and Http2" suggests: it will apply), but: I've seen this problem with a non-TLS endpoint that is attempting to serve both HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 traffic - it gets a little confused and tries to respond with HTTP/1 response to an HTTP/2 request (this doesn't happen with a TLS endpoint, due to the handshake working differently). In my case, the fix was to tell the server to *only* serve HTTP/2. This can be done in appSettings.json under the `Kestrel` / `EndPoints` node, by specifying `"Protocols": "Http2"`, or in Program.cs by specifying `listenOptions.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2` in the `ConfigureKestrel` call. When I want to serve HTTP/1 and HTTP/2 without TLS, I've always had to use different ports etc.

Comment: Great, this fixed it! Thanks a lot. But it seems that it can't connect to the 'external world' when running in Docker now? I can't ping it and it can't connect neither to the local DB. 110% sure it wasn't happening before switching to http 2 only