# gRPC Asp Net Core 3.1 APIs don't work when running on Kubernetes

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, istio

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521993/net-core-3-1-grpc-client-with-unencrypted-http2-connection/67522111#67522111), I've set my Asp Net Core 3.1 app to only use HTTP2 protocol. Actually it solved my issue, at least locally.

But when I deploy the server app on Kubernetes, my client app (a net core 3.1 demo console app), throws an exception:

> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset
> reason: connection termination

I did some research online and it seems to be related to the Kubernetes configuration. Since this is the first time I use Kubernetes, I don't exactly which part is wrong and why.

My deployment script is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: ***-service-beta
    namespace: ***-staging
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: ***-beta
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: ***-service-beta
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: ***-service-beta
                  image: __image_name__
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 16050
                  resources:
                      limits:
                          cpu: 500m
                          memory: 2Gi
                  env:
                      - name: ***
                        value: ***
                      - name: ***
                        value: ***
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    namespace: ***-staging
    name: ***-service-beta
spec:
    selector:
        app: ***-service-beta
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 16050
          targetPort: 16050
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    namespace: ***-staging
    name: ***-service-beta
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: istio
spec:
    rules:
        - host: ***-service-beta.***.k8s.***.***
          http:
              paths:
                  - backend:
                        serviceName: ***-service-beta
                        servicePort: 16050
```

My client code. Not sure if I need to set the port?

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);

    using var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://***-service-beta.***.k8s.***.***");
    var client = new EventService.EventServiceClient(channel);
    var reply1 = await client.GetTrackEventAsync(new GetTrackEventRequest { Name = "01Austra14" });
}
```

The server provides both REST and gRPC APIs on the same port. RESTful APIs are working.

I would be glad if anyone can help me

Comment: I see you are using `istio`....based on that you should use `istio-gateway` and `virtual-service`...I'm a little confused