# Getting this `Grpc.Core.RpcException` when using a ASP.NET Core gRPC Service over http

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-5

I made these two simple applications:

- ASP.NET Core gRPC Service
- Console Application

##### ASP.NET Core gRPC Service `Startup.cs`

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseGrpcWeb(new GrpcWebOptions { DefaultEnabled = true });

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();

            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

##### Console Application

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(
            "http://localhost:10027/",
            new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Insecure,
                HttpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(new HttpClientHandler())
            });

        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

        Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = "John Doe" }).Message);
    }
}
```

I've used both *IIS Express* and *IIS* for deployment and I get the following exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.Http2ConnectionException: The HTTP/2 server sent invalid data on the connection. HTTP/2 error code 'PROTOCOL_ERROR' (0x1).
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowProtocolError(Http2ProtocolErrorCode errorCode)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(Boolean initialFrame)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowRetry(String message, Exception innerException)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ThrowShutdownException()
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendHeadersAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean mustFlush)
   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Web.GrpcWebHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)")
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
```

## Update

Apparently, I solved the issue using these steps:

- Setting the `Kestrel.EndpointDefaults.Protocols` to `Http1` (in appsettings.json)
- Changing the target framework for console application from `.NET 5` to `.NET Core 3.1`
- Updating the console application code as below

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
        };

        var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(
            "http://localhost:10027/",
            new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                HttpHandler = new GrpcWebHandler(httpHandler)
            });

        var client = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

        Console.WriteLine(client.SayHello(new HelloRequest { Name = "John Doe" }).Message);
    }
}
```

But, it still doesn't work when setting target framework to `.NET 5`!

Comment: GRPC -> HTTP/2 by default -> you need TLS or go back to HTTP 1.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.Net Core 3.1 gRPC client with unencrypted HTTP2 connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521993/net-core-3-1-grpc-client-with-unencrypted-http2-connection)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No, it doesn't help.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto How to go back to HTTP 1.1?

Comment: gRPC explicitly only works on HTTP2; and annoyingly: you need to explicitly specify HTTP2 *only* in the protocol when using non-encrypted data - if you try using the hybrid http-1-or-2, it doesn't work (when not using TLS); so: try specifying the protocol explicitly (again, it must be HTTP2)

Comment: Here's an example that configures HTTP2: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/blob/main/examples/dotnet-grpc/DN_Server/Program.cs

Comment: Thanks, @MarcGravell. Please see my update.

Comment: @HadiFooladiTalari can I just confirm: you really mean Http1 ? because... gRPC is Http2 specific - I would be very surprised if it worked correctly on Http1